# "Somebody of place" - use and meaning

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

From time to time I see sentences like:

> Dr. Berard of France, Michael Davis doctor of Manchester
>   ...

I am not sure about the exact meaning.
Is the person currently living and working there?
In what case should I use the "person of place" like sentences?

Comment: It means they were probably born there, and live there.

Comment: Your ... may be crucial here. Is it 'University'? // As an aside, there may be a title 'Michael Davis Doctor' (a post commemorating/endowed by Michael Davis). We need full linked actual examples. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Woodrow_(professor)) has, for example, << [James Woodrow] was also appointed as Professor of Chemistry, Geology, and Natural Philosophy at the University of Georgia, but never took the position. Instead, Woodrow took a position at Columbia Theological Seminary in 1861, becoming the first Perkins Professor of Natural Science. >>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This usually will mean where they live, work, graduated, or were born in the "of" place that is mentioned. You could say:

> Dr. Kennedy of Texas

also

> Dr. Kennedy of the University of Texas at Austin

also

> Dr. Kennedy of Austin, TX

also

> Dr. Kennedy of the Houston Medical Center

---

You have to be careful with the syntax though. You cannot say:

> Mr. Kennedy, a doctor of Austin, TX

rather you would say:

> Mr. Kennedy, a doctor *in* Austin, TX

or

> Mr. Kennedy, a doctor *at* the Houston Medical Center

In your example:

> Michael Davis doctor of Manchester

This would be wrong. It implies that Michael Davis is THE doctor of all of Manchester, or that he is the only doctor serving the Manchester area.

Rather, it needs to be:

> Michael Davis, a doctor in Manchester

or

> Michael Davis, Ph.D., of Manchester